# Problems getting ftell() in binary append

Tags: c++, c

I've got some code that was working on a server until it was moved to a different system.  The problem seems to be here:

given a structure I've defined elsewhere:

```
user1_type user1;              /* structure containing user data */
user1_type *user1_ptr=&user1;
```

this routine appends the record to the end of the file

```
if ((dfile=fopen(filename,"ab+"))==NULL)  
  error_message("Unable to open file for append.",filename,1);
 else { /* append data */
 user1.recid=ftell(dfile);               /* update file position */

 fwrite(user1_ptr,sizeof(user1),1,dfile);
 fflush(dfile);
 fclose(dfile);
```

I can confirm the data gets appended in the file, but the value of user1.recid always returns 0 - any ideas why?

UPDATE:  Looks like the issue is not all implementations require a fseek() after fopen().   I obviously need an fseek(dfile,0,SEEK_END); before I do a ftell() when appending.  But if I want to read from the beginning of a text or binary file, is it also customary to place a fseek() right after fopen?  Does it vary depending upon the file type?

Comment: does ftell return a long or a 64.  How is user1 defined?

Comment: @cleblanc  `long int ftell(FILE *stream)`

Comment: typedef struct {
      long recid;
      char dataid[5];              /* USER1 */
      ..
    } user1_type;

Comment: From the docs for ftell() that I use: "Note that when a file is opened for appending data, the current file position is determined by the last I/O operation, not by where the next write would occur."  You must call fseek() first.

Comment: apparently on some implementations the file pos for a+b is set at EOF without a seek being needed (FreeBSD)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

...so (in addition to bkVnet's answer) you must use `fseek(dfile,0,SEEK_END)` to seek to the end, ask `ftell` the position and divide that by `sizeof(user1_type)` to get the record id (i.e. the number of records already in the file, so plus 1 for the new record).

Comment: I think you may be correct sir!

Here's what I think is happening.. on my previous FreeBSD implementation, when a file is opened for append, the position is already moved to the end of the file, so ftell() works in one way, but under CentOS, you have to add     fseek(dfile,0,SEEK_END);  in order to get ftell() to give you something other than 0!

Comment: I believe my code problems are the result of getting invalid record number references when appending.

Comment: will a fread() change the position of ftell() or is that implementation dependent and I may need to also do a seek?

Comment: also does a fseek need to be done if a text file is opened a la fopen(filename,"at"); ?

Answer (score 3):

From MSDN's documentation of [`ftell`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0ys3hc0b.aspx)

> The position returned by `ftell()` is expressed as an offset relative
>   to the beginning of the stream
>
> If no I/O operation has yet occurred on a file opened for appending,
>   the file position is the beginning of the file.

This gives you an offset of 0 relative to the beginning.

So when you call `user1.recid=ftell(dfile);` no I/O operation has occurred on the stream yet so `ftell()` returns 0 indicating the file pointer position is at the begining.

Comment: I don't see such behavior under gcc 4.9.3/cygwin. Can you provide supporting documentation?

Comment: This has been working in the past, but the code was moved into a virtualized environment.. would that cause any change?

Comment: @R-Sahu: "_Note that when a file is opened for appending data, the current file position is determined by the last I/O operation, not by where the next write would occur._" (MS VC2008)

Comment: @R Sahu This behaviors is for MSVC. I am not sure about gcc. i'll try to look into it.

Comment: @bkVnet, thanks for adding the clarification and the supporting documentation.

Comment: @Trent Three As mentioned in the comment by R Sahu, this behavior may be implementation dependent(i'm not sure), the behavior i provide in the answer comes from MSDN documentation of ftell, but again you can use fseek() to seek to the end of file before using ftell

Comment: This explains things.... I had numerous c-based programs running under FreeBSD... they all broke when I migrated them to virtualized CentOS7.

I need to know what I need to do to make this legacy code work properly.. I am finding that seek and/or appends aren't behaving the same.

Comment: @TrentThree you can use `fseek(dfile,0,SEEK_END)` to position the pointer to the end before calling `ftell()`. This should not interfere with further calls to write data to the file.

Comment: I was storing the record number in the file, and I was getting it by ftell() prior to appending, so I was storing invalid data in the file when I migrated to a different OS

Answer (score 3):

This behavior of `ftell(dfile)` here would be implementation defined. From C11 7.21.3 (similar wording in previous C standards):

> If a file can support positioning requests (such as a disk file, as
>   opposed to a terminal), then a file position indicator associated with
>   the stream is positioned at the start (character number zero) of the
>   file, **unless the file is opened with append mode in which case it is
>   implementation-defined** whether the file position indicator is
>   initially positioned at the beginning or the end of the file.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I suspected i could be implementation defined.

Comment: Nicely explain OP's "code that was working on a server until it was moved to a different system"

Comment: WOW thanks... ok, I've got to figure this out... what's happening is I need to know the file position before I do the write.

Comment: I was using FreeBSD and ftell() returned something different on that implementation.. now under CentOS, it works differently... do I need to open the file with a different mode/command?

Comment: I believe Paul Ogilvie has the right answer- a manual seek has to be executed before getting the position, the need for which may be implementation different.. I'm testing this right now

Comment: @TrentThree: I don't think you need to worry about different implementations - just do the `fseek(dfile,0,SEEK_END)` regardless.  If the file pointer is already positioned there, it's effectively a no-op, and for implementations that start with the file pointer at the beginning it will give you the behavior that you need.  If you open the file in append mode, a write will *always* seek to the end of the file before performing the write.