# How to count number of line from binary file for C programming

Tags: c, readline

```
typedef struct {
    int ID;
    char name[30];
    char position[20];
    char department[20];
    char password[10];
    int contactnumber;
    int age;
    char emailaddress[30];
}admin;
admin info;

void registration() {
    int count=1001,y;
    FILE* Admin;
    Admin = fopen("Admin_info.bin", "ab");
    if (Admin == NULL) {
        printf("Unable to open file");
    }

    printf("\tPlease insert your informantion below\n");
    printf("\tID:  ");
    scanf("%d", &info.ID);
    printf("\n\tName: ");
    scanf("%s", &info.name);
    printf("\tPosition: ");
    rewind(stdin);
    scanf("%s", &info.position);
    printf("\tDepartment: ");
    scanf("%s", &info.department);
    printf("\tPassword: ");
    scanf("%s", &info.password);
    printf("\tContact Number: ");
    scanf("%s", &info.contactnumber);
    printf("\tAge: ");
    scanf("%d", &info.age);
    printf("\tEmail Address: ");
    scanf("%s", &info.emailaddress);

    fwrite(&info, sizeof(admin), 1, Admin);
}
```

*I wanted to auto generate the ID. Therefore, I need to read the number of line from binary file and add by 1 and I don't know how to read the number of line. Please someone help me

Comment: Note `rewind(stdin)` is not good

Comment: Your code seems incomplete (loop missing?) which makes your question is not clear. You read the ID, so what's the problem?

Comment: @PaulOgilvie, I want to auto generate the ID instead of typing manually.

Comment: Open file in read mode; read records until end; remember last ID read; close file and open in append mode; ask info, using ID+1; write record at end.

Comment: user15330212, "line" implies text.  Perhaps use "record" to refer to one `admin` of binary data.

Answer (score 1):

You should've mentioned that it's about the file you are writing to. And there are no actual lines, since you are writing binary data to it.

You could first open the file in `rb` mode, `fseek` with `0, SEEK_END`, `ftell` to get the file size in bytes, close it again, then divide the file size by `sizeof(admin)` to get your ID. Then apply your code.

EDIT after comment by chux:

It is not necessary to first open the file in `rb` mode and close it, as I had suggested. It is sufficient to leave it open in `ab` mode as done in your code and just add the `fseek` and `ftell`. Depending on the system, even the `fseek` is not required, but this seems not to be guaranteed by the standard.

I just found a very much related question here: [Problems getting ftell() in binary append](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36896230/problems-getting-ftell-in-binary-append)

Comment: See little reason to "close it again".  Even `feek()` might not be needed with the file opened in _append_ mode.

Comment: Good point. `fseek`and `ftell` will work in append mode as well, so there is no need to open in read mode and close. However, I think the standard doesn't guarantee that `ftell` will always return the file end in append mode.